# Meaning of "To lick a knack"

Tags: phrase-meaning

My wife and I have a question about the phrase "to lick a knack". But we can't find anything on the net, any ideas?

My interpretation is that it may mean "to fix something that is a little thing".

Comment: Where did you come across this phrase? Can you post a link?

Comment: Never heard it, that I can recall.  You need to provide a reference, or at least describe the context where you encountered it.

Comment: What´s an interpenetration? It doesn´t sound comfortable, somehow.

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: @Cascabel I think they meant *interpretation*.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey No doubt, but I couldn´t let it pass without comment, especially as they managed to get _lick_ , _little thing_ and _penetration_ in on the same post.

Answer (score 1):

This phrase does not seem to exist.

- A [Google Search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=safari&hl=en-gb&ei=3wlJWMbRFemEgAaVzaeQAw&q=%22lick+a+knack%22&oq=%22lick+a+knack%22&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3...78558.83642.0.84473.2.2.0.0.0.0.153.252.1j1.2.0....0...1c.1.64.mobile-gws-serp..0.0.0.yIudw6T4Q5E) for `"lick a knack"` returns only this question.
- [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Lick+a+knack&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) also returns nothing
- Nor do various idiom dictionaries

Have you typed this correctly or is it just a phrase that only you use?

Comment: @Cascabel Ok, thanks for letting me know. While this answer could be improved I don't see any point in doing so, considering the fact that this question is closed.